# How to have search functionality in PDF within Unity and have the content displayed as AR overlay?

Tags: c#, pdf, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, texture-mapping

I'm looking into this concept for creating AR in Unity using PDF content:

Have a picture of an object as AR target, then a command to search through a PDF database for the PDF file that contains the same/similar picture, and finally to overlay the text content in that PDF on my initial object.

From your experience, do you know if this can be achievable somehow in Unity currently?

My findings for now are that there are PDF reader plugins for Unity, that you can display PDF files in a browser (Application.OpenURL) or resorting to the PDF-image format conversion. But haven't found much on search features inside PDFs (text or image search).

Instead of searching for a PDF file that contains the same picture used as AR target, maybe search for a unique "text" and get the PDF where that string is located? 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/37408/can-the-unity-dash-search-for-content-within-files
https://askubuntu.com/questions/41829/how-can-i-search-for-files-in-unity

And would it be possible to pull out the text content in the PDF and display it as overlay while target detection?

Can you also advise on trainings I could take that'll be helpful for the above? Or propose alternatives?

Thank you.